# output content of each line after a search string

Tags: powershell

I have a debug log which spits out certain numbers that follow a preset error message.
For instance

> 08:29:25.178 [DEBUG] Error lookup ID 2834
>
> 08:29:25.179 [DEBUG] Error lookup ID 2834

The main reason I want to do this is to be able to then just output the unique instances of this ID (in above example would be just one 2834). It is not possible otherwise as the timestamp in the line makes it unique. So therefore I need to only output the id at the end (in this case 2834).

I currently have following script which works but I am wondering if there is not a more efficient/elegant way to do all this.

```
    $tempfile='tempfile.txt'
    $tempfile2='tempfile2.txt'
    $tempfile3='tempfile3.txt'
    $finalfile='missingIDs.txt'
    
    get-content 20180131.log -ReadCount 1000 |
    foreach { $_ -match " Error lookup ID" } > $tempfile
    
    get-content $tempfile | % { $_.Split(' ')[-1] } >$tempfile2
    gc $tempfile2 | sort | get-unique > $tempfile3
    
    gc $tempfile3| get-unique > $finalfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restating the problem for clarity:

**Given lines of input, find " Error lookup ID" followed by a string of numbers, `ID`. Return all unique `ID` found in the input.**

```
$testInput = @(
"08:29:25.177 [INFO] system started 5342"
"08:29:25.177 [DEBUG] Error lookup ID 2834"
"08:29:25.178 [TRACE] entered something"
"08:29:25.179 [DEBUG] Error lookup ID 2834"
"08:29:25.179 [DEBUG] Error lookup ID 2836"
)

$testInput | % { if ($_ -match ".*Error lookup ID (\d+)"){$Matches.1} } | Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: thank you!
This is the final script:

     $finalfile='missingIDs.txt' 
    Get-Content *.log | % { if ($_ -match ".* Error lookup newsid from RT ID (\d+)"){$Matches.1} } | Select-Object -Unique |Sort-Object -Unique | Out-File $finalfile

Comment: just one more addition i need. i have another file with descriptions for these ids. 
how do i know reference these resulting ids and then search for each one in another file to get associated description for the id (essentially just search for each ID in the other file and print out the whole line with that id in it). thanks!

Comment: You can probably read the descriptions file into a hash table with key:id and value:description string. Do some experimenting and post another question with what you tried if you get stuck.

Comment: my powershell skills are quite lacking to get to that level. i did post a question but i got shot down with "this is not a script writing service" :)
i will try but my guess is it will take me weeks to figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the intermediate text files, and using the pipeline instead.

```
$finalfile='missingIDs.txt'
Get-Content 20180131.log -ReadCount 1000 |
    foreach { $_ -match " Error lookup ID" } |
    foreach { $_.Split(' ')[-1]} |
    Sort-Object -Unique |
    Out-File $finalfile
```

This makes your whole process more efficient, as there's no disk writes/reads.

Comment: in this line `foreach { $_ -match " Error lookup ID" }` any reason for not using Where-Object? I can see output is different when changed, only returns last ID line